# Getting error: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendmail

I am having some issues with my send mail. I made some changes to this and now am getting this error.

When I ran the code before this error, I had this set up to email the first email in the address Detail. The first email in the address detail is Billing. Which would be okay if the email is meant to go to billing. In my system I have a billing address, and a shipping address and sometimes those are the same location. So I added some code and CC so that it sends to the proper email.

Here is my code:

```
string subject = " Request For Payment";
string body = "Please see the attached Request";
string touser = data.AddressDetail.FirstOrDefault()?.EmailAddress ?? "MyEmailAddress";
string ccAddress = data.AddressDetail.Where(x => x.IsShipping == true).FirstOrDefault()?.EmailAddress;
bool val = ExtendedViewModels.SendEmail(touser, ccAddress, subject, body, FilePath, "InfoEmailAddress");
```

So the `touser` will be the first email, the CC will be to the Shipping email. I realize I may send 2 emails if shipping and billing are the same. Not sure how to get around that. This is the first attempt I have made with this code. I should also say that the email is a Canadian email with a `.ca` although I dont know that this is the issue. This instance is also a case where billing and shipping are the same. This is only 1 record with bits set for billing and shipping.. In other cases there would be 2 records with billing and one with shipping.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I ran this with breakpoints on the code. I have all the info I am supposed to. It faults when It goes to send the mail. The only thing that sticks out to me is that it is a .ca email and not a .com. Is there something in sendmail that needs to be added for this?

UPDATE:

I found my issue. Order of importance! I guess Order matters. I will put it in an answer below!

Comment: If you run it under your debugger, inspect everything, it WILL tell you where the problem is. Have you done this?

Comment: Actually no. I sent it from the live site. I at first thought it was an issue with the live site. I will run it and see what I get..

Comment: You have "FirstOrDefault()" which is getting only one item.  Change to ToList()

Comment: See update above.. I am getting what i am supposed to..

Comment: It is unlikely that a .ca email address would be the cause of the problem may be something else is wrong with it?!

Comment: This might be a silly question, but do Caps matter in an email? I looked at the email in outlook and the first 2 letters are in caps..

Answer (score 0):

Order is Important in this case. While adding the `ccAddress` I did not take care in where I placed it. I was sending an email to what the subject was..

```
string subject = " Request For Payment";
string body = "Please see the attached Request";
string touser = data.AddressDetail.FirstOrDefault()?.EmailAddress;
string ccAddress = data.AddressDetail.Where(x => x.IsShipping == true).FirstOrDefault()?.EmailAddress;
if (touser == ccAddress)
{
  bool val = ExtendedViewModels.SendEmail(touser, subject, null, body, FilePath, "InfoEmail");
}
else
{
  bool val = ExtendedViewModels.SendEmail(touser, subject, ccAddress, body, FilePath, "InfoEmail");
}
```

Then in the Send mail I had to add an `if statement` where ccAddress may be null.

```
public static Boolean SendEmail(string touser, string subject, string ccAddress, string body, string FilePath,  string fromAddress)
    {
        try
        {

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(fromAddress)
            };
            msg.To.Add(touser);
            if (ccAddress != null)
            {
                msg.CC.Add(ccAddress);
            }
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = body;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            if (FilePath != "")
            {
                msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FilePath));
            }

            SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Your UserName", "Your Password"),
                Port = 587,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            smt.Send(msg);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

I put the rest of the code up there to make it a complete answer..

Comment: `Order is Important in this case` - the order of arguments when calling a function is important in *every* case.

Comment: Note that the `?? "MyEmail"` is not needed, it could even cause problems. It is usually fine to have **`null`** as the `To` address, as long as there is at least one valid CC and/or BCC address. Or never mind what I said if you fill in your own actual address...

Comment: No I do not fill in the address it comes from a db record. I originally did not write this code, so I was also wondering if that was put there in case there was no email. This is not the case because I would not send an invoice to an account that does not have an email. I will remove it.. thanks